# How to pronounce "sheet" properly?

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronounce *sheet* to minimize the risk of confusion with *shit*?

Usually what one means is clear from the context, but it'd still be very awkward if it accidentally sounds like *shit*.

Comment: @R C Quite a few French friends have asked me the same question. Also 'beach' and 'bitch'. :-)

Comment: I wanna sheet on my bed and I wanna fork on the table!

Comment: It seems like the confusion might be prone to go the other way around. (If _shit_ and _sheet_ sound like near homophones, I'm guessing that it's the former that's being said with the off pronunciation.)

Comment: I had a roommate once from Greece.  He had trouble distinguishing these words, both in hearing and speaking.  Also confusing them with *sit* and *seat*.  All four of them seemed about the same to him.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your KIT and FLEECE vowels aren’t far enough apart.

The difference is that [the KIT vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel) is /ɪ/, and [the FLEECE vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel) is /iː/, with a bit of length added to it, too.

The KIT vowel is a little bit more open and a little bit further back than the FLEECE vowel:

[image: IPA vowel chart]

Many minimal pairs exist for these two, with *bit* and *beet* perhaps the most often cited.

This is an error sometimes made by Spanish speakers in English. I am guessing that your first language does not consider the KIT and FLEECE vowels to be distinct phonemes the way English does.

Comment: For those who don't make the distinction, I find the extra is that the FLEECE vowel is also diphthongized, that is length is not enough, it must also have the y-glide or in IPA /ij/.

Comment: @Mitch For some speakers, perhaps, but certainly not for others, who have only a monophthong there not a diphthong. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects).

Comment: Yes, that's true. But the question was how to emphasize the tense /i/ to avoid confusion with lax /ɪ/, and diphthongization of /i/ is one strategy.

Comment: I have noticed that my romance-language-speaking friends tend to retain the pure vowel sounds instead of adopting the diphthongization of words - and despite that, their "shit", "sit", "ship" and "bit" frequently sound like "sheet", "seat", "sheep" and "beat".  (I say "huh?" a lot.)

Comment: I wanna sheet onna bed and fork onna table